# Cache static class's Data in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, caching

I have static class that holds some info

```
public static class SampleDataCache
{
    private static Dictionary<string,SampleData> cacheDict = new Dictionary<string,object>()

    public static Get(string key)
    {
        if(!cacheDict.Contains[key])
            cacheDict.Add(key,new SampleData());

        return cacheDict[key];
    }
}
```

And when I refresh page I want SampleDataCache to keep its data.

Can I achieve this in simple way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the cache, in its current form, is stored in memory then the data is naturally cast into oblivion when the page refreshes - that's a new instance of the application starting there. You might, however, be interested in utilising isolated storage in order to persist data per-user.

With isolated storage you essentially have a contained file system into which you can store data and then further retrieve it. One step in the right direction could be to make a class you want to represent a 'piece' of cached data, make it serializable, then using your static class as the cache controller you can read and write these objects from and to isolated storage.

[Quickstart: Isolated Storage in Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/)

Comment: Uhm... how about the `ApplicationLifetimeObjects` property of the `Application` class? Why go to isolated storage?

Answer (score 3):

You should remember about extra if (nobody understand that ;/). And also you can be more generic and type safely. You can Look below, this is example of well written caching pattern also can be used as an aspect.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SampleDataCache {

  public class SampleData {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public static class DataCache {
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, object> CacheDict
      = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    private static readonly object Locker = new object();

    public static T Get<T>(string key, Func<T> getSampleData) {
      if (!CacheDict.ContainsKey(key)) {
        lock (Locker)
          if (!CacheDict.ContainsKey(key)) {
            CacheDict.Add(key, getSampleData());
          }
      }
      return (T)CacheDict[key];
    }
  }

  public class Program {
    private static SampleData CreateSampleData() {
      return new SampleData() { Name = "Piotr Sowa" };
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      SampleData data = DataCache.Get("Author", CreateSampleData);
    }
  }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Yeah... this works in WinForms and WPF. Not in Silverlight. And yes, while it does explain a generic implementation nicely (albeit over engineered) it does not actually address the problem. Remember, just because it's static doesn't mean it solves the problem, especially in Silverlight and/or ASP.NET apps.